# ThreeJS : Hide faces edges in webgl Render.

Tags: three.js

When i view my scene from far distance i see faces edges on the objects.[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzJq3.jpg)

At a certain angle i can see the lines clearly like wireframe. 
How to remove these.

Thanks

Comment: I am almost certain it is a problem with your model.

Comment: Ok, Model are from sketchup warehouse. Can you tell me what problem do you think it can be

Comment: poly flow, poly count, smoothing groups, it could be many things.

Comment: I have tried any model and same problem exists. Line that i see if UVW Mapping edges.

Comment: What material are you using? Without seeing something, I can only guess

Comment: Earlier camera near was 1. Changed it to 10. Now those lines have reduced